# Braintree Drop-In UI v.zero how to retrieve the payment ID with PHP / to stay PCI QSA A

Tags: braintree, pci-compliance

I'm new to braintree and I read that we need to be PCI QSA compliant...
There is the QSA A type and for that the v.zero ( Drop-In UI ) seems to be the best approach.

I followed the steps in: https://developers.braintreepayments.com/start/hello-client/javascript/v2

The form have action="/checkout" (or any other path...) but this tutorial doesn't provide the needed code to retrieve the payment status (example paid, ID of transaction).

I don't want to store credit card info.

Answer (score 0):

<sub>Full Disclosure: I work as a developer for Braintree</sub>

That portion of the tutorial outlines how the client sends the credit card information to the Braintree servers which returns a payment method nonce via the post parameters.

You can then use the payment method nonce to create and inspect transactions and payment methods while remaining PCI compliant. For example, if you have the form that posts to `/checkout`, you could do something like this in the checkout logic:

```
$amount = '10.00';    /* replace with the amount you want */
$nonce = $_POST["payment_method_nonce"];

$result = Braintree\Transaction::sale([
    'amount' => $amount,
    'paymentMethodNonce' => $nonce
]);

if ($result->success){
    $transaction = $result->transaction;    
    /* inspect the transaction here */
} else {
    /* handle any errors */
}
```

All of this is detailed in the next portion of the tutorial which can be found [here](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/start/hello-server/php) and if you have any questions you can always reach out to [Braintree support](https://support.braintreepayments.com/).

Comment: Ok Thanks for the clarification. I did an ajax test, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36232558/braintree-what-do-i-paste-in-braintree-createyourclientsideencryptionkey/36232882#36232882